# How to process large datasets in python? Error: killed 9

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python on VScode program. I have a spectrum, that consists of ~75000 points. I'd like to subtract the noise from the data using asymmetric least squares method. Here is the code that I use:

```
contents = pd.read_excel("spectrum.xlsx", usecols=[0, 1])
contents.columns = ["Freq.", "Intensity"]
intensity = contents["Intensity"].to_numpy()


def baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter=10):
    L = len(y)
    D = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diff(np.eye(L), 2))
    w = np.ones(L)
    for i in range(niter):
        W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L)
        Z = W + lam * D.dot(D.transpose())
        z = spsolve(Z, w * y)
        w = p * (y > z) + (1 - p) * (y < z)
    return z


baseline_als(y=intensity, lam=10, p=0.05)
```

Here is the example of the data:

```
 wn  Intensity
0      13500.00793    0.00187
1      13500.02300    0.00093
2      13500.03806    0.00012
3      13500.05313    0.00069
4      13500.06819    0.00241
```

When I run the line  `baseline_als(y = intensity, lam = 10, p = 0.05)` I get a message: `Killed: 9`. I read that it is linked to too much memory consumption. So, how could I rewrite the code, to consume less of the memory? Also, when I run the file on command window on mac, it gives the same error, so it is not VSCode issue.

Comment: `del contents` might help a bit; you don't need the dataframe since you've already copied the data you care about into `intensity`... Beyond that, can your algorithm work in chunks of `y`? That might help.

Comment: Secondly, it might be a good idea to use a debugger or at least add some `print()` statements so you can tell where exactly your program gets `Killed`.